# xsl code to get a range of nodes from xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml like this:

```
<persons>
<person name="a">
</person>
<person name="f">
</person>
<person name="b">
</person>
<person name="g">
</person>
</persons>
```

Suppose i want to have all nodes between the one with name "f" and the one with name "g"
So, parsing it with xslt, it should produce:

```
<person name="b">
</person>
```

How can i do this??

Appreciate any help, thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a simple list (not groups) this XPath 1.0 expression:

```
/persons/person[preceding-sibling::person[@name='f']]
               [following-sibling::person[@name='g']]
```

If there are groups, this XPath 1.0 expression:

```
/persons
 /person
  [count(.|preceding-sibling::person[@name='f'][1]
            /following-sibling::person[@name='g'][1]
             /preceding-sibling::*) = 
   count(preceding-sibling::person[@name='f'][1]
          /following-sibling::person[@name='g'][1]
           /preceding-sibling::*)]
```

In XPath 2.0 you could use for both cases:

```
/persons/person[preceding-sibling::person[@name='f'][1]
                 /following-sibling::person[@name='g'][1] >> .]
```

In XSLT 1.0 you could use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="kPersonByMarks" match="person"
             use="concat(generate-id(
                            preceding-sibling::person[@name='f'][1]),
                         '+',
                         generate-id(
                            following-sibling::person[@name='g'][1]))"/>
    <xsl:template match="person[@name='f']">
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('kPersonByMarks',
                                 concat(generate-id(),'+',
                                        generate-id(
                                           following-sibling::person
                                                      [@name='g'][1])))"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<person name="b"></person>
```

**Edit**: Correct "including" expression for XPath 1.0, and XPath 2.0

Answer (score 0):

I would use the position() function to select nodes whose position is greater than the position of the lower limit, and less than the position of the upper limit.

Comment: Well, that was my thought too but how is it done? I'm struggling to find a solution right now. (Although my biggest problem is that somehow many XPath functions are not found in the standard Java XPath implementation...)

Comment: hmm 2 sec may have simple solution

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
     match="persons/person[not(../preceding-sibling::person[f])]"/>
```